# Zend_Form_Element_File::getValues() renaming uploaded file

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element

I'm fairly new to Zend Framework and I've encountered something strange, which I'm hoping somebody will be able to explain. Consider following code:

```
<? class Form extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
    $upload = new Zend_Form_Element_File('upload');
    $this->addElement($upload);
    }    
}

if ($_POST)
{
    $form = new Form();
    var_dump($form->isValid($_POST));
    $values = $form->getValues();

    var_dump($_FILES, file_exists($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
    exit;
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

If uploading any file the var_dump of $_FILES will output that the uploaded file doesn't exist. Comment the $form->getValues() line, and it's there. After investigating the issue - getValues renames the actual file (ie. /tmp/php/phpBUI9M3) to whatever was the name of the uploaded file, keeping it in the same folder (ie. /tmp/php/test.png). Why? I was under the impression that getValues shouldn't alter any data.

PHP: 5.2.17,
Zend: 1.10.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:

> Per default the file will automatically be received when you call getValues() on the form. The reason behind this behaviour is, that the file itself is the value of the file element.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file

There are some examples of how to change this behaviour if that's not what you want to happen, but it seems logical to me.

Comment: Well, in my understanding - Zend kicks in when the file's already on the server, in the tmp folder; if I were to specify different destination directory, or renaming scheme, this would make sense as the original data were to be stored in the $_FILES, the paths / filenames would be in the File element, as per file operations. However, in this instance renaming takes place, which isn't really something that should be done by default - consider for example two files, with the same name: after the upload, I'll end up only with one.

Comment: Fair point. I can't see anything in the code that would explain this.

Comment: Couldn't this setup a race condition if multiple users are uploading the same form simultaneously?  Where can I find examples to override this behavior?